# Tkinter window not opening, but if I comment out a line, it works

Tags: python, tkinter

So I *was* trying to create a GUI in pygame, but after a while, I just decided to re-write it in tkinter. I need to create 3 bars, one being a canvas, the other 2 being empty. The size of the left bar is `leftbarwidth` and the right `rightbarwidth`, set to 200 and 300 respectively. So far I have this (The logic of the program not included)

```
 1 from tkinter import *
 2 
 3 def windowsizeupdate(event):
 4     preview.config(width=event.width-leftbarwidth-rightbarwidth, height=event.height)
 5 
 6 root = Tk()
 7 root.title("TITLE HERE")
 8 root.geometry(f"{leftbarwidth + rightbarwidth + 200}x600+{int(screen.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - (leftbarwidth + rightbarwidth + 200) / 2)}+{int(screen.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - 300)}")
 9 root.minsize(800, 600)
10 root.attributes("-topmost", 1)
11
12 preview = Canvas(root, bd=0, bg="#800000", cursor="dot", width=200, height=600)
13 preview.place(x=leftbarwidth, y=0)
14
15 root.bind("<Configure>",windowsizeupdate)
16 root.mainloop()
```

But whenever I run it, I just get this:

[image: app not responding mac]

After commenting out line 4, and replacing it with `print(event.width-leftbarwidth-rightbarwidth, event.height, leftbarwidth)`, I discovered
everything works, and all the values should work with the config function!

But if I put in this:

```
 1 from tkinter import *
 2 
 3 def windowsizeupdate(event):
 4     print(event.width-leftbarwidth-rightbarwidth, event.height, leftbarwidth)
 5     preview.config(width=event.width-leftbarwidth-rightbarwidth, height=event.height)
 6 
 7 root = Tk()
 8 root.title("TITLE HERE")
 9 root.geometry(f"{leftbarwidth + rightbarwidth + 200}x600+{int(screen.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - (leftbarwidth + rightbarwidth + 200) / 2)}+{int(screen.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - 300)}")
10 root.minsize(800, 600)
11 root.attributes("-topmost", 1)
12
13 preview = Canvas(root, bd=0, bg="#800000", cursor="dot", width=200, height=600)
14 preview.place(x=leftbarwidth, y=0)
15
16 root.bind("<Configure>",windowsizeupdate)
17 root.mainloop()
```

I see my console output looks like this:

[image: long console output]
Can someone explain this to me!

Comment: Please don't post code with linenumbers, it makes it difficult for us to copy and paste your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you resize the window, that raises another `<Configure>` event and recalls your handler.  You need to detect that the event wat not triggered by your change:

```
def windowsizeupdate(event):
     if event.x != leftbarwidth:
        preview.config(width=event.width-leftbarwidth-rightbarwidth, 
height=event.height)
```

Comment: You are misunderstanding what i'm trying to do. Although that just may be the function name. If the window is resized, keep the bars on the left and right the same size, and change the size of preview. The function doesn't change the size of the window, it changes the size of a widget in the window, so how would it be calling it's self?

Comment: @TheMystZ: you shouldn't need to use a `<Configure>` event to accomplish that.

Comment: No, I understand what you want to do.  When you change the size of ANY window, `<Configure>` is raised.  When I went back to test, the "busy" thing didn't work, but I think you can detect that it's not the preview window by checking for the X position.

Comment: Thank you, the new answer worked!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to keep the left and right side windows to be a fixed size, you don't need to do that via a binding on the `<Configure>` event. This sort of thing is exactly what the geometry managers `pack`, `place`, and `grid` are for.

You're using `place` which makes this problem harder to solve since it's difficult to have the width of a widget to fill the space between other widgets. A better solution is to use `grid` or `pack`.

For example, using `grid` you can set a minsize for the left and right columns and then let the middle column fill all of the additional space.

```
from tkinter import *

leftbarwidth = 200
rightbarwidth = 300

root = Tk()
root.minsize(800, 600)
preview = Canvas(root, bd=0, bg="#800000", cursor="dot", width=200, height=600)

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=leftbarwidth)
root.grid_columnconfigure(2, minsize=rightbarwidth)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
preview.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Using `place()` is not hard for this case: `preview.place(x=leftbarwidth, y=0, relwidth=1, width=-leftbarwidth-rightbarwidth, relheight=1)`.

Comment: @acw1668: I suppose you're right, though I remain convinced that `pack` and `grid` are superior for most layout problems.